# How do I provide custom output streams in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

I am working on an application the will need to sequentially encode/decode a series of bytes, and put them to a stream once they have been processed.

My plan was to subclass ostream and provide a constructor `MyEncodeStream(istream)` using istream.

I must admit though I am at a loss as to what to do next, which methods should be overridden?
What is the standard facility for doing this.

Please provide example code for a this simple case:

1. A char is pulled from the input buffer
2. The char is manipulated by char `manipulationFunc(char in)`
3. The char is put to a buffer
4. MyEncodeStream stops blocking so the char can be read
5. Does ostream provide a read function that should be overridden which operator << calls, or is operator<< the function that should be overridden?

Comment: I am aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482116/inherit-stdostream I have googled, I just couldn't get a straight answer.

Comment: With regards to 5, I think you mean `operator <<`, and that is implementation defined (differs per compiler).

Comment: It isn't clear why you need anything special like that.  It seems like you could just read the character from an istream, call the function, then write the result to an ostream.

Comment: I am writing a class that encapsulates the encoding process, provides an input facility and provides an output stream for someone else to read at their leisure.

Comment: Indeed you are mixing up your functionality, you want an encode/decode class(s), then you should be able to use the normal I/O streams to read/write your encoded/decoded data.

Comment: Very related question [How to write custom input stream in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086417/how-to-write-custom-input-stream-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: Why not just write your encoding/decoding as a Filter for [boost.iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html)?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, I was confused. What I wanted to do was to subclass an input stream with an input stream as an argument for the constructor, that way when the custom input stream is read it can read from the standard input mechanism.  I was looking up subclassing output streams, which is why google wasn't turning up many results.